# may we write constructor/destructor using trailing return type syntax?

Tags: c++11

Question as title.
May we write constructor/destructor using trailing return type syntax?
If yes, what should be on the place of return type?

Comment: What do you think the return type would be in that case??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because something is nice and shiny doesn't mean you should try to use it everywhere.

Trailing return types are useful if

1) A function returns a value. Constructors and destructors don't. So, in that respect, your question makes no sense.

*and*

2) The return type requires compile-time evaluation. i.e. in generic programming when you don't know the return type: you mark the return as `auto` and use the trailing return syntax `-> decltype(`.

Comment: may I buy a closing parenthesis?

Comment: Of course; along with all the other bits inside the `decltype` which, by the way, like `sizeof`, are expressions that are not *evaluated*. I would have used an ellipsis (`...`) but felt that would be more confusing. That said, I'm starting to think that this answer is weak so may remove it.

Comment: Thanks.
So trailing return type syntax could be applied on all functions except constructors, destructors and type conversion operators, right?

Comment: @stefan This may help: `)`

Comment: It can be applied to things with a void return type too.  This can be useful with things like std::enable_if.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors and destructors do not have a return type, nor do they return anything. Sorry.